# Error en LayoutInflater

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, tengo el siguiente error en la sección del layoutinflater, este es el código que se utiliza actualmante.

```
public void mostrardatos (){
    String url = "http://192.*.*.*/oficina/buscar_vehiculos.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    **LayoutInflater registro;
                    registro = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabla2,null,false);**
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

en la sentencia this, me marca este error "'from(android.content.Context)' in 'android.view.LayoutInflater' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONObject>)'", al parecer no funciona el layoutinflater en un volley (json), creo que eso es el mensaje, lo otro que adjunto una imagen que me posiciono en el error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ojala que me puedan ayudar con este pequeño problema, pero como les menciono siempre soy nuevo en etas lides de android studio, así que por favor un poco de paciencia conmigo, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: El error te dice que está esperando un context, pero le estás pasando un JSONObject, prueba con getContext().

Answer (score 0):

El problema sucede en este punto,

```
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabla2,null,false);
```

aquì es incorrecto usar `this` ya que estas haciendo referencia al mètodo y no en realidad al contexto, puedes usar  `getApplicationContext()` para solucionar el problema:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.tabla2,null,false);
```

Comment: **Muchas gracias por tu ayuda @Jorgesys, me ayudaste enseguida funciono con lo planteado por ti**, y ahora me muestra todos los datos que pretendía en la tablelayout, y nuevamente mil gracias por tu ayuda, como soy nuevo como se debe hacer para realizar la puntuación.

Comment: Que bueno @Hector para votar y marcar como solución la respuesta revisa [tour], saludos.